# Which Objective-C framework do I have to use to record my screen?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, quicktime, pyobjc, appkit

I'm already recording from my iSight from a python script using the pyobjc bridge and the QTKit framework.

Which framework/device/... should I use to capture the video of my screen instead of the built-in iSight?

P.S. I'm using Leopard (not Snow Leopard) and thus I don't have the Quicktime X API at my disposal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<del>OpenGL. There's sample code for this on Apple's developer site (SonOfGrab, IIRC).</del>

As of Lion, you should [use AVFoundation to record the screen](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/qa/qa1740/).

Comment: Can it also take videos or only screenshots?

Comment: I finally found the right examples:
- Sync snapshot: http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/samplecode/OpenGLScreenSnapshot/index.html
- Async video: http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/samplecode/OpenGLScreenCapture/index.html

Thanks for the insight

Comment: @robbie_c: They've been moved to the Legacy library: http://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/samplecode/OpenGLScreenSnapshot/ http://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/samplecode/OpenGLScreenCapture/ The latter includes a link to [a relevant replacement document that shows how to do this task using AVFoundation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/qa/qa1740/).

Comment: `AVScreenCaptureInput` looks like an interesting class. It's a bit sad that there's no `initWithWindowID:(CGWindowID)id` constructor. I guess that changing window sizes was too much of a headache for them to think about.

Comment: @robbie_c: Yeah. You may want to ask a separate question about how to record a particular window to the screen without just recording wherever it happens to be.